# Allow some CSS-rule in HTML's style attribute

Tags: c#, html, css, regex

Could you guys suggest me how to remove some CSS-rule inside the HTML's syle attribute by using regex **in C#**.

I want only the text-align and the margin rule are allowed. Else is replace by "" ( empty string ).

For example:

```
<p style="text-align: left; margin: 5px;color: red;"><strike>iiyuyuiy</strike></p>
```

Will be become like this.

```
<p style="text-align: left; margin: 5px;"><strike>iiyuyuiy</strike></p>
```

The color:red; removed.

Comment: Why would you need to do that as opposed to just overwriting the CSS, with !important if necessary?

Comment: I want to prevent some smart-user who know HTML and CSS and they want to break my rule.

Answer (score 1):

If you are famiiar with jQuery try **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

#### JQuery

```
$('selctor').css("color", ""); //passing value as null.
```

#### Pure JS

```
document.querySelector('#selctor').style.color= '';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, parsing html with regex is fraught with danger. Someone is sure to offer you a Dom parser solution, so this answer is mainly to discuss the regex aspects of things.

I usually like to offer a regex solution anyhow, but the task you propose to undertake is truly an appalling one for regex (though no one is blaming you for this). Why?

**Semi-colon are not a perfect delimiter of CSS rules**

To match and remove rules, you need to know where they stop. For CSS rule, that is semi-colons. But if a CSS rule has a semi-colon aside from the terminating one, the regex will fail. I don't have an example in mind but it's a frequent point of discussion.

**In a world without troublesome semi-colons...**

If you had your back against the wall and if semi-colons were not a problem, here is one approach that would work in C#, thanks to its infinite-width lookbehind.

```
(?<=style="[^"]*)(?:(?:text-align|margin)[^";]*;|(\b[^";]*;))
```

In the replace delegate, using this regex, we would replace the match with an empty string only when capture Group 1 is set.

This time I won't offer sample code as I want to encourage anyone from doing this. Nevertheless, if you were interested in the technique for study purposes, I highly recommend you read this question about [matching patterns except in certain contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204).